# disable select dropdown base on a condition

Tags: html, angular, select

I am currently building an angular application. I need to disable my select dropdown in a specific condition (when price is equal to 0).

```
                   <div>
                      <label>Min Adults</label>
                      <select
                       
                        [(ngModel)]="roomDetail.minAdults"
                        (click)="minOccupancyLoop()"
                        id="occupancy"
                        
                      >
                        <option
                          *ngFor="let occupancy of minimumOccupancySet"
                          value="{{ occupancy }}"
                          [selected]="occupancy == roomDetail.minAdults"
                          
                        >
                          {{ occupancy }}
                        </option>
                      </select>
                    </div>
```

I need to disable this dropdown when **price=0**.
I search questions already on StackOverflow but didn't find a satisfying answer. I hope someone answers this.

**Thank you in advance**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

disabled property in option would do the trick;

```
<option *ngFor="let occupancy of minimumOccupancySet"
               value="{{ occupancy }}"
               [selected]="occupancy == roomDetail.minAdults"
               [disabled]="price === 0"
 >
{{ occupancy }}
</option>
```